# how to use background-image and hover

Tags: css

I've got the following:

```
table.inactiveTable thead {
    background: #efe;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#efe,#ded);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,0% 0,0% 100%,from(#efe),to(#ded));
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(gradientType=0,startColorstr=#efe,endColorstr=#ded);
    height: 40px;
}

table.inactiveTable th:hover {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#efe,#F8FFB5);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,0% 0,0% 100%,from(#efe),to(#F8FFB5));
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(gradientType=0,startColorstr=#efe,endColorstr=#F8FFB5);
    cursor : pointer;
}
```

then, in runtime i add `asc` class for that element, the style is the follows:

```
.asc, .asc:hover{
    background-image: url(arrow_up.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position : left;
}
```

It works - i mean there's the correct image in the background. But it disappeads on hover event - `th:hover` works.

I mean: this is what i see when i add `asc` class:

[image]

and this is what i get when i hober over this element:

[image]

How can i make them work together - i mean to make inage stay while changing the gradient colours?

My goal is to be able to add a background image for the specific (table column header) element on click event, but not to loose this image on hover.

**added:**

html:

```
<table id='leads' class='inactiveTable'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan='2' onclick="sorter.sort(this, 'unumber')">id</th>
            <th rowspan='2' onclick="sorter.sort(this, 'bccu')">bccu</th>
...
```

Comment: Actually, your question contains nothing about design :)

Comment: you have to submit part of html where this CSS code is applied.

Comment: @archil, so i'm not designer enough to realize it =)

Comment: Ok so make your css more specific like th.asc, th.asc:hover .

Comment: @k102 designers design - result of their work is generally picture, drawing of what should be achieved. Making that picture alive, implementation by using html and css, is developer's job.

Comment: @archil, ok, excuse my bad english: i meant creating a web layout (don't know the job title, but that's not a developers job)

Comment: @k102 I want to help you understand that **implementing** web layout is indeed developer's job :). Developer may not **create** layout, but he is responsible for implementing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add-

```
.inactiveTable th.asc, .inactiveTable th.asc:hover{
    background: url(arrow_up.png) no-repeat left top;
}
```

It will work

Comment: my goal is to be able to add a background image for the specific (table column header) element on click event, but not to loose this image on hover.

Comment: Add this - .inactiveTable th.asc, .inactiveTable th.asc:hover{
    background: url(arrow_up.png) no-repeat left top;
}

Comment: Great! That's the solution =)

Comment: If you would have added your goal in question first "my goal is to be able to add a background image for the specific (table column header) element on click event, but not to loose this image on hover."

It would have been much easier to answer :)